# Error in IPython Shell

Tags: python, ipython

I've just started playing around with IPython, and it's got some pretty cool features. I especially like that it "remembers" input from previous shell sessions. I am having some trouble, however, with the tab completion.

Here's an example of my console:

```
In [5]: a.__class__.python(58387,0x7fff70630c20) 
malloc: *** error for object 0x103133b40: incorrect checksum for freed object - 
object was probably modified after being freed.

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

`a` is a string, and I've typed `a.__class__.` and then hit `TAB` and this is the result

Has anyone else had this problem? Any fixes?

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Which version are you using? I have Python 2.6.5 + IPython 0.1 in Ubunto 10.4

Comment: Ditto, Python 2.6.5 + IPython 0.10 on WinXP. What is the string? When I type `a.__class__.` and hit `TAB` I get a list of available members

Comment: I'm on Python 2.6.1, IPython 0.10, and OSX 10.6.4. The problem is sporadic. It will happen only sometimes with that example, or really anytime I try to use tab complete. Thanks for trying to reproduce.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem either on cPython 2.6.3 with IPython 0.10 on Windoze XP. Hmm, a puzzler...